# How to assign a unique_ptr value from within a lambda

Tags: c++

I have a situation where I need to assign a unique ptr value from within a lambda function.

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeType> unique_ptr_obj;

// Lambda below has fixed return type.
bool var = ()[unique_ptr_obj=std::move(unique_ptr_obj)]-> bool {
 unique_ptr_obj = GetUniqueObject();
 return true 
} ();
 
// Should be able to use unique_ptr_obj
UseUniqueObject(unique_ptr_obj.get());
```

However, as expected `unique_ptr_obj` is nullptr as it was moved into lambda. Is there a way I can populate `unique_ptr_obj` from within a lambda and be able to reuse it later ?

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this ? Should I convert `unique_ptr_obj` to `shared_ptr` ?

Comment: "as expected unique_ptr_obj is nullptr" ? The code does work as expected?

Comment: The value of `unique_ptr_obj.get()` is now a nullptr. I want it to point to the object created via `GetUniqueObject`.

Comment: not sure if I understand. Do you want to capture `unique_ptr_obj` by reference ?

Comment: If you want to modify an object passed/captured to/by something, you want to pass/capture that object by reference

Comment: questions about issues with code should include a [mcve]

Comment: Does `GetUniqueObject` return a raw pointer? Please show a minimal reproducible example as already asked for.

Comment: Unrelated: But `bool var = ()[ ...` doesn't look like C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the declaration of your lambda to capture `unique_ptr_obj` by reference:

```
bool var = [&unique_ptr_obj]() -> bool {
    // Whatever the next line does, now it changes that variable by reference.
    // Otherwise you were changing a local copy.
    unique_ptr_obj = GetUniqueObject();
    return true;
} ();
```

Comment: right, I think that is what I was looking for. Is it possible to capture just `unique_ptr_obj` by reference ?

Comment: @danishsodhi `&unique_ptr_obj` instead of just `&`

Comment: So you need to capture some other vars too? Then you would have to list them explicitly, only with no `&`.

Comment: afaik `[&]` does capture only `unique_ptr_obj` when thats the only variable being refered to in the body.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, that's true.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Oh, I assumed that OP wanted to use some other variable (not shown in the original code snippet) in the body of lambda. Only not by reference. Well, that's how I understood the first comment.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to share ownership. Or maybe you do, but it won't help with the lambda assigning something to `unique_ptr_obj`, hence using a `shared_ptr` is not the solution.

You also do not want to move from `unique_ptr_obj`. Sloppy speaking, moving from something means leaving it in an empty state.

If you want a function to modify its argument then you pass by reference. If you want a lambda to modify something in the outer scope you let it capture it by reference.

This is the same whether its an `int` or a `unique_ptr`:

```
int x = 0;
bool value = [&x]() { x = 42; return true; } ();
         //   ^^ capture x by reference

assert(x == 42);
```

Comment: right, I think that is what I was looking for. Is it possible to capture just `unique_ptr_obj` by reference ?

Comment: @danishsodhi in the example only `x` is captured by reference, nothing else

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that capturing a unique_ptr by reference is similar as capturing any other variable type. Is that correct ?

Comment: @danishsodhi Yes. A `unique_ptr` is no different.

Comment: @danishsodhi `std::unique_ptr` isnt magic. Its a custom type like any other, its only "special" because its included in the standard library